# Core Data How to fetch hierarchy?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have simple Core Data application. There is only one model object and its name is `Data`. It has `count` and `name` attributes. It also has two relationship to itself. One for `subDatas` which is To-Many relationship and the other one is `parentData` which is To-One relationship and inverse of first.

Here is core data graph look like:

[image: Object Graph]

Here is my problem. I want to fetch this Data objects with their relationships. Say If have 2 parent `Data` object and every `Data` object has 2 sub `Data` object I want to fetch them just like this hierarchy. Here is the code that I use to create this hierarchy in core data:

```
Data *parent1 = [self createDataWithName:@"Parent1" andCount:@10 inContext:context];
Data *subData11 = [self createDataWithName:@"Sub1-1" andCount:@11 inContext:context];
Data *subData12 = [self createDataWithName:@"Sub1-2" andCount:@12 inContext:context];

NSMutableOrderedSet *parent1Set = [parent1.subDatas mutableCopy];
[parent1Set addObject:subData11];
[parent1Set addObject:subData12];

parent1.subDatas = [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithOrderedSet:parent1Set];

Data *parent2 = [self createDataWithName:@"Parent2" andCount:@20 inContext:context];
Data *sub21 = [self createDataWithName:@"Sub2-1" andCount:@21 inContext:context];
Data *sub22 = [self createDataWithName:@"Sub2-2" andCount:@22 inContext:context];

NSMutableOrderedSet *parent2Set = [parent2.subDatas mutableCopy];
[parent2Set addObject:sub21];
[parent2Set addObject:sub22];

parent2.subDatas = [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithOrderedSet:parent2Set];


NSError *error;
[context save:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}

// Helper function to create Data object
- (Data *)createDataWithName:(NSString *)name andCount:(NSNumber *)count inContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Data"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:context];
    Data *data = [[Data alloc] initWithEntity:entity
               insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];
    data.name = name;
    data.count = count;

    return data;
}
```

And here is the code that I use to fetch:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetch = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Data"];
NSArray *result = [context executeFetchRequest:fetch error:NULL];
```

The `result` array contains all the `Data` objects included sub items to. But I want only parent objects. How can I fetch them?

Thank you.

Comment: You mean using a `NSPredicate` like this one: `@"subData != nil"`. If you add this to your fetch, you'll only have `Data` that have at least one `subData`, or maybe find the one who don't have `parentData`: `@"parentData == nil"`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think checking for nil will work, but you might check that the number of child objects is greater than zero.  The following should work:

```
request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Data"];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"subDatas.@count != 0"];
NSError *err = nil;
NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&err];
```

Also, note that when you're loading Core Data you should probably not be setting the subDatas directly.  Instead, use the CoreDataGeneratedAccessors.  You will find the accessor methods in the Data.h file if you set up Core Data properly.  These methods will take care of generating both the subDatas relationship and its inverse relationship.

So, delete the following:

```
NSMutableOrderedSet *parent2Set = [parent2.subDatas mutableCopy];
[parent2Set addObject:sub21];
[parent2Set addObject:sub22];

parent2.subDatas = [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithOrderedSet:parent2Set];
```

And (using CoreDataGeneratedAccessors) replace it with:

```
[parent2 addSubDatasObject:sub21];
[parent2 addSubDatasObject:sub22];
```